# MySQL select records from related table

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables:

**products**
id
name

**product_variants**
id
product_id
name
barcode

I want to select all products with one query containing one field with the amount of related variants and one field with all related barcodes (seperated by space).

So for example this output:

```
product_id    product_name    product_variant_count    product_variant_barcodes
1             Product 1       3                        1234567890 0987654321 5432109876
2             Product 2       1                        6789054321
3             Product 3       2                        1234509876 3456781290
```

Is this possible?

Comment: take a look at group_concat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `GROUP_CONCAT` is perfect for this.

Selecting from products and joining onto product_variants:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, COUNT(pr.id) AS product_variant_count, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(pr.barcode  SEPARATOR ' ') AS product_variant_barcodes
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_variants pr ON (p.id = pr.product_id)
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked. I only had to add GROUP BY products.id

Comment: @user3320021 Good catch. I'll add that to the question.